# Staying DRY in Rails 3 with scopes and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, associations, arel

Here are the relevant facts:

1. Each `topic` `has_many` `comments`.
2. The `Comment` model has a `scope` called `very_popular`, which we'll pretend involves comparing a several of its columns.

   ```
   def self.very_popular
     # lots of cool stuff
   end
   ```
3. The `Topic` model has a `scope` called `exciting`, which includes all `topics` with `very_popular` `comments`.

Number 3 is where I'm stuck. The following results in a missing method exception, and as pitiful as it sounds, I don't know what else to try!

```
def self.exciting
  join(:comments).very_popular
end
```

How can I re-use the `very_popular` scope from the `Comment` model in the `Topic` model's scope?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to use a scope in one model in another model, directly at least. Maybe you can group all your scopes in a file then include it in your models (from /lib)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the scope from another model directly. What you can do is merge the queries.
`Topic.joins(:comments).merge(Comment.very_popular)`

Ryan explains it beautifully here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3